# Trigonometric limit

Tags: limits

I couldn't find this limit , can someone help me?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(x)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) - \sin\left( \frac 1x\right)}$$

Comment: Have you tried L'Hôpital? It's a clear 0/0 and you won't get anything worse than $cos(0)$ and some polynomials.

Comment: I have no idea about Arctan derivation

Comment: [Then look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions#Derivatives_of_trigonometric_functions_and_their_inverses) unless it's homework and you can't use things you haven't been taught. All trigonometrics and their inverses have simple derivatives and the same also extends to the related set of [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).

Comment: There is no other way to find the limit without L'Hôpital ?

Comment: Maybe not L'hospital, but one way or another, you're going to have to deal with the derivative of arctan.  Either by series or by L'hospital or some way that tries to dodge the derivative, but essentially uses it anyway.

Comment: Well i tried the L'Hôpital , its still 0/0 . :/

Comment: There always is. You could try using the [various addition rules](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) to obtain, for example, $\tan^{-1}(x+1) - \tan^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1}(1/(1+x+x^2))$, and the same trick in the denominator. Maybe something wil pop out.

Comment: @Falker123 If it's still 0/0 check for possible cancellation of common terms, if none are left, repeat. One often ends up applying the rule several times – but always do check the assumptions!

Comment: But I'm not saying it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. By using [Taylor series expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition), as $u \to 0$, one has
$$
\begin{align}
\arctan u&=u-\frac{u^3}{3}+o(u^3)
\\\sin u&=u-\frac{u^3}{6}+o(u^3)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to \infty$ $\big($with $u=\frac1{x}$ or $u=\frac1{x+1}$$\big)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\arctan x&=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1x =\frac{\pi}2-\frac1x+O\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)
\\\arctan (x+1)&=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1{x+1} =\frac{\pi}2-\frac1x+\frac1{x^2} +O\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)
\\\sin \frac1x&=\frac1x+O\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)
\\\sin \frac1{x+1}&=\frac1x-\frac1{x^2} +O\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)
\end{align}
$$ then, as $x \to \infty$,

> $$
> \frac{\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(x)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) - \sin\left( \frac 1x\right)}=\frac{\frac1{x^2}+O\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)}{-\frac1{x^2}+O\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)} \to -1.
> $$

Comment: I always find it amusing when an answer starts with "Hint" and ends with the solution. ;p

Comment: @Bye_World As a teacher, I think many details are missing... Hence the use of 'hint' ;)

Comment: Thanks , but can u tell me what does O(1x3) means ?

Comment: An expression $f(x)$ is equal to $O(x^3)$ as $x \to \infty$, if we have a constant $C$ such that $\left|f(x)\right|\leq C  x^3$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Great , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use identities:
$$
\sin\theta -\sin\varphi=2\sin\left(\theta-\varphi\over2\right)\cos\left(\theta+\varphi\over2\right)\\
\arctan x-\arctan y=\arctan\left(x-y\over1+xy\right)
$$
Then,
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(x)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) - \sin\left( \frac 1x\right)}=
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x(x+1)}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x}\over2\right)\cos\left( \frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}\over2\right)}\to\\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}\right)}{2\sin\left(-\frac{1}{2x(x+1)}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2x+1}{2x(x+1)}\right)}\to-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2x(x+1)}\right)}
$$
Now, use corollaries from the first remarkable limit:
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}\right)}{\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}}\frac{\frac{1}{2x(x+1)}}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2x(x+1)}\right)}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}}{\frac{1}{2x(x+1)}}\to
-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}}{\frac{1}{2x(x+1)}}\to\\
-\frac{2}{2}\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x+x^2}{1+x+x^2}=-1
$$
Which implies:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(x)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) - \sin\left( \frac 1x\right)}=-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\arctan(x+1)- \arctan(x) = \int_x^{x+1} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}.$$

A lower bound for this integral is $1/(1+(1+x)^2)\cdot 1,$ an upper bound is $1/(1+x^2)\cdot 1.$ We also have

$$\sin(1/x) - \sin (1/(x+1)) = \int_{1/(x+1)}^{1/x} \cos t\, dt.$$

Here a lower bound for the integral is $\cos (1/x)\cdot (1/x- 1/(x+1)),$ an upper bound is $\cos (1/(x+1))\cdot (1/x- 1/(x+1)).$ Noting $1/x- 1/(x+1) = 1/(x(1+x)),$ we can put all this together to see

$$\frac{1/(1+(x+1)^2)}{\cos (1/(x+1))(1/x(1+x))} \le \frac{\arctan(x+1)- \arctan(x)}{\sin(1/x) - \sin (1/(x+1))} \le \frac{1/(1+x^2)}{\cos (1/x)(1/x(1+x))}.$$

Both bounding functions $\to 1,$ hence so does the middle expression. Since I switched the sign of the denominator at the beginning (because it was easier for me to think about), the desired limit is $-1.$